# python random number error (blackjack game)

Tags: python-2.7, blackjack

when i run the code, the deck is printed out the first time but it prints 'none' the second time. i assume the deck list is being overwritten for some reason but cant figure out why. any help would be appreciated.

```
class Deck(object):
  def __init__(self,deck=['2c','3c','4c','5c','6c','7c','8c','9c','tc','jc','qc','kc','ac','2d','3d','4d','5d','6d','7d','8d','9d','td','jd','qd','kd','ad','2h','3h','4h','5h','6h','7h','8h','9h','th','jh','qh','kh','ah','2s','3s','4s','5s','6s','7s','8s','9s','ts','js','qs','ks','as']):
      self.deck=deck

  def shuffle_cards(self):
      self.deck=random.shuffle(self.deck)

l=Deck()
print l.deck
l.shuffle_cards()
print l.deck
```

Comment: `random.shuffle` returns none. Don't assign it to `self.deck`.

Answer (score 0):

shuffle works in place (https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

```
random.shuffle(self.deck)
```

will work instead of

```
self.deck=random.shuffle(self.deck)
```

btw: mutable default parameter value is not perfect

Comment: thanks! are you saying i should us a tuple instead? what benefit does that bring?

Comment: if you make two instances of Deck and in one of them you append sth to self.deck it will be visible in the other one